# Laravel 5 : Setting limitations on uploaded files without changing php.ini?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I learned it is required to modify the values in `php.ini` in order to set the limitation for uploading files. However, I'm in a situation where I can't touch `php.ini`.

Let me explain the problem briefly.

```
<input type="file" name="thumbnail" accept="image/*">
```

I'm trying to get the `thumbnail` and get it in a controller.

```
if($this->request->hasFile('thumbnail')){
    $file = $this->request->file('thumbnail');
    //Other tasks
}
```

If the file size is over a certain point, I'd like to prevent it and show a warning. However, apparently, if the uploaded file is over the limit, **`request->hasFile()` returns false even though it's actually true**.
(I saw that by `dd()`)

It's probably impossible to catch this type of error by `hasFile()`, since it simply doesn't catch it.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Why you don't use validation rule [max](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-max) for your purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use validation rule [max](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-max)

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    ...
    'thumbnail' => 'max:30000', // kilobytes
    ...
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for you advice. For some reasons, when I upload a file which is larger than the limit, the file size is always '0', whereas files which are under the limit are treated as expected. Anyways, this advice will be helpful for future development. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Fist of all, make sure that your form uses `multipart/form-data` enctype.

```
<form action="/upload-image" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="thumbnail" accept="image/*">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

To get the file size you can use `getClientSize()` function of [UploadedFile](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html) object.

So to limit the size and show a warning, you can do something like that:

```
if ($this->request->file('thumbnail')->getClientSize() > 5){
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['thumbnail', 'File is too big. Limit is 5MB.']);
}
```

Then in the view print the error.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Unfortunately, `getClientSize()` returned `0` when I uploaded a file of larger size than the limitation, while it returned the right file size when I uploaded a file which is under the limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the validation rules?

**Validating Files**

Rule:

```
size:value
```

The field under validation must have a size matching the given value. For string data, value corresponds to the number of characters. For numeric data, value corresponds to a given integer value. For files, size corresponds to the file size in kilobytes.

Comment: Not sure that size rule matches with @YMD needs. It checks if the file size equals to the given value, but not check size exeeds it.